# tinymce: "default_link_target:'_blank'" of autolink plugin doesn't work in IE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

I Initialized tinymce as below, but in IE, default_link_target does not work. tinymce version is 5.10.2

```
tinymce.init({ 
  selector: '#mytextarea',
  height: 800, 
  plugins: 'link, autolink',
  default_link_target: '_blank'
});
```

In IE, a tag created by autolink. No target attribute.

```
<p><a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/</a></p>
```

In Edge, a tag created by autolink.

```
<p><a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">http://www.google.com/</a></p>
```

Comment: I've created a fiddle with autolink and default link target: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/7Shaab
It seems to be working fine in IE11. Which version of IE are you using? Please make sure it is supported: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/system-requirements/#supportedwebbrowsers